# C++ local initialization?

Tags: c++

So there is something called *static initialization* and *dynamic initialization* and apparently they do not describe a certain way of initializing but *when* things are initialized. Static and dynamic initialization can only used to designate initializations of non-local variables...

So what about local variables? *When* do their initializations happen and what is it called? I cannot find anything called *local initialization*? I mean wouldn't it be quite convenient to have a name for *when* they are initialized since *value-/ aggregate-/ etc. initializations* describe *what* initialization happens and the can even be used with *static and dynamic initialization*(as far as I know) which makes it just a bit more confusing to me..

Hope this made somewhat sense to you :)

Comment: Local variable can be initialized in single "pass" as you cannot forward declare local variable. For global, it is more complicated.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I have already checked, which I did before asking this question... But I could not really find the answer and regarding "This is because storage commonly known as "local" or "stack" is officially called "automatic"", I am not really asking about the storage but the initialization. Also, I do not really get why you compare storage and initialization...  I mean for example, dynamic initialization has nothing to do with dynamic storage duration..

Answer (score 0):

Local variables are initialised when they are constructed.
*When* doesn't need a name, only *what* is interesting.

Comment: "When doesn't need a name, only what is interesting." you are only talking about local variables here, right?

Comment: Which part of the answer (and your question) is suggesting that I'm not?

Comment: Not sure.. that was why i asked, but then I assume that was a yes. :)

Comment: Anyway, thanks for the answer! Is this specified somewhere in the Standard ? If so, could you tell me where I should look at, please?

Answer (score 0):

Local variables are initialized when the scope is entered/reentered.
There is no specific terminology in c++ for local variable initialization.

Consider following example

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    int n = 0;
    printf("%d ", ++n);  
     /* prints 1 1 1  - the previous value is lost
        every time n is initialized with 0 when scope is entered
     */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple logic is all local variables (static or dynamic) get initiated when only they are called in run time.

```
class Test
{
public : 
    Test(string text)
    {
        cout << (text) << endl;
    }
};
void print()
{
    Test t1("local");
    static Test t2 ("local static");
}
    int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    cout << "begin" << endl;
    print();
    cout << "end" << endl;
}
```

anwers

```
begin
local
local static
end
```